# My contract hasn't been deployed

Tags: remix

I don't know what happened pls help, My contract was made but hasn't been deployed but when I put the address code on remix it says contract has been deployed but when click start it says (Transct not payable) it says the same thing on every other options I don't know to do pls help. pls contact me I can give you pictures of the problems.

Comment: Please, provide more details. Source code, screenshots of the error messages, describe your setup: blockchain, wallet, etc.

Comment: Provide more information. Could you please provide additional details for better assistance? This could include sharing relevant transaction IDs, source code snippets or any error messages.